# How do I plot field of view of an earth-based observatory in Galactic Coordinates?

Tags: python, maps, astronomy

I would like to plot in Galactic Coordinate the sky field-of-view of an earth-based observatory (e.g. MAGIC). Something like this from [Liu et 2016](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/0004-637X/826/1/63/pdf).

I already know how plot source positions on a 2D projection of the sky (following this tutorial: http://learn.astropy.org/plot-catalog.html).
Is there a simple way to plot the field of view using astropy and/or astroplan and/or matplotlib?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Great question, although I can't think of an answer at the moment... I'd suggest asking on astronomy.stackexchange.com, where there may be more people who already had to do that. Good luck!